# Using youtube official php sdk show "The session state did not match.NULL string"

Tags: php, api, authentication, youtube, sdk

While i'm using Youtube official PHP SDK,  it shows an error message like this on the authorization callback url:

> The session state did not match.NULL string(10) "1786553519"

Then I check the `session['state']` found it is null.

Who can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Maybe related, [YouTube PHP API: The session state did not match NULL string(10) “1494600193”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34902616/608639)

Comment: You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)